# Find out all parameters in a function from string

Tags: php, regex

I want to find out all parameters in a function, but i get an error when i use a "(" or ")" char in my function parameter.

My RegEx: `/@GetText(\(\s*([^)]+?)\s*\))/`
I use http://www.phpliveregex.com for debugging (funktion: preg_match_all).

My search strings:

- `@GetText("Hello World", "Example")` <= Works
- `@GetText("Hello World!", 1234)` <= Works
- `@GetText("This makes errors-->  Hello(World)")` <= It does not work
  Works

Comment: Your examples are unclear.Can you show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get just a single match on the entire string?

I tried this, but not sure if this is what you're looking for:

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/hY7bB7/1)

```
/@GetText\((.*)\)$/g
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match recursive substrings, you will need to use a [recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) regular expression inside of a lookahead to retrieve all of the overlapping matches, something like this should work:

```
$re = '~@GetText(?=(\((?:[^()]+|(?1))*+\)))~';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/387179)